# Cannot insert data into a table in db using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a problem to insert a new row of data into a table I created via JDBC. It throws SQLException after the ExecuteUpdate() line.

Below I provide a code which created the DB and the Table in this DB. The second part has the code which is supposed to insert values into row in a PatientsData table.

```
public class DbSetUp {

private static Connection con;
private static String mySqlString = "CREATE TABLE PatientsData" +
        "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        "fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL," +
        "lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL," +
        "sex VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL," +
        "insurance VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL," +
        "profession VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)";
//private boolean end;
private static String strTemp = "CREATE TABLE PatientsTemp" +
        "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        "name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL," +
        "date DATE NOT NULL," + 
        "temp NUMERIC NOT NULL)";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:PatientDb;create=true");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Db not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Statement statement = null;
    try{
        statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.execute(mySqlString);
        statement.execute(strTemp);

    } catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

The above code works fine throwing no exceptions. I assume that both tables have been created and the DB exists:)

Not the part which is supposed to insert data:

```
public Patient createNewPatient(int id, String fname, String lname,
        String sex, String insurance, String profession) {

    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("to na poczatku");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:PatientDb"); 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PatientsData VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        System.out.println("Prepared Statement");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        System.out.println("set int id");
        ps.setString(2, fname);
        ps.setString(3,lname);
        ps.setString(4,sex);
        ps.setString(5, insurance);
        ps.setString(6,profession);
        System.out.println("set string profession");
        result = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(result);
        return new Patient(id,fname,lname,sex,insurance,profession);
        //System.out.println("set string profession");


    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("SQL exception");
        return null;
    }

}
```

The line: result = ps.executeUpdate(); throws SQLException, I have no idea where is the mistake. I have added derby.jar into my build path.

Comment: please post exception details.

Comment: Please show the exception error message and stack trace

Comment: 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL120407181654820' defined on 'PATIENTSDATA'.
 at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)'

Comment: You're inserting duplicate keys, which is illegal. This is not related to your code but to your data.

Comment: Yes, now I know :) Thanks for reminding about printing stack trace. Now I have another problem, but I'll try to fix it myself first.

Answer (score 1):

your SQL statement is wrong

```
INSERT INTO PatientsData VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

neets to be

```
INSERT INTO PatientsData(columnname1,columname2...) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

i suspect...didnt really read about the functionality but looks fine.

Ah misread ... its a Derby query... my format is from MS SQL.. so.. donno if its answer

Comment: The statement isn't wrong. It is allowed to leave out the column names, but that is considered bad style. Explicitely listing the columns in the INSERT statement is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be you are trying to insert duplicate value in ID column

Ensure that you are generating unique value for ID.